# Import the image in GIMP software

Tags: gimp

When opening more than two images in GIMP version 2.8.14 system gets hanged. Even if I change the preference folder path the problem persists. How can I keep the system from hanging?

Comment: GIMP is not GIS software, this question might be more suitable for a different community. Your problem is impossible to debug without lots of more information (how big are the images, what specs does your computer have, what operating system etc).

Comment: Have you tried maybe using inkscape?  I much prefer it to gimp for creating maps